# Uppdating azure-sdk-for-go library dependancies

Tags: azure, go, dep

What is the best practice to carry out this task?

What I tried so far, simply run command `dep ensure -update github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go`
that threw the following error:

```
    Warning: the following project(s) have [[constraint]] stanzas in Gopkg.toml:

  ✗  github.com/gravitational/trace
  .....
```

`dep ensure` gives me similar error as `dep -update` command. `dep check` gives following output:

```
# Gopkg.lock is out of sync:
github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/arm/compute: imported or required, but missing from Gopkg.lock's input-imports
.....
```

and

```
# vendor is out of sync:
cloud.google.com/go: no digest in Gopkg.lock to compare against hash of vendored tree
github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go: no digest in Gopkg.lock to compare against hash of vendored tree
....
```

This is a rather large project. Should I manually remove all existing dependencies in the code to the old `import azure-sdk-for-go`? or should `deb` be able to carry out this task?
Iw'e tried various hacks to get this working, like for instance, manually modifying the `Gopk.lock` file, deleting the `azure-sdk-for-go` folder in the `vendor` folder, but so far I had no luck. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your updating from a quite old version, since `github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/arm/compute` has been deprecated and removed almost a year ago while this SDK was still in preview.

To move forward, you should update your compute path to `github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/compute/mgmt/2018-10-01/compute`. There will be several other breaking changes to adopt since then as well.